# When to use AWS CloudfrontWebDistribution and when to use AWS Cloudfront Distribution

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, aws-cdk

I see in [aws-cdk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/) there are two constructs:

- [CloudFrontWebDistribution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-cloudfront.CloudFrontWebDistribution.html)
- [Distribution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-cloudfront.Distribution.html)

Each have different props that do not look compatible with each other.

I'm wondering which one to use?

Comment: Welcome to SO! In order to help your, you should ensure that we can replicate/understand your problem. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The AWS `CloudFrontWebDistribution` is the original method for working with CloudFront distributions. But now, they had implemented a new method that is provided by `Distribution`. You can use both CloudFrontWebDistribution as well as Distribution for working with CloudFront distributions, but `Distribution` has a simpler interface and they receive new features faster. So, it is recommended to use `Distribution` instead of `CloudFrontWebDistribution`.

Comment: To support this argument, here is an implementation of Cache Policies in CloudFront Distribution. 
CloudFrontWebDistribution is pending implementation since Oct 2020 but Distribution got it already implemented and merged.

https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/pull/10656

Comment: Good to know. Maybe they should mention it in the CDK API documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CloudFrontWebDistribution unless you're looking to have RTMP (streaming) distribution then you can configure the Distribution